# SQL Server 2008 stored procedure calling MATLAB

Tags: sql-server-2008, matlab

Is it possible to call a MATLAB command within a stored Procedure?, something like

```
EXEC(MATLAB_COMMAND(Argument1,argument2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any working experience concerning SQL Sever 2008, I would say no. Referring to the mysql documentation, a stored procedure is described as:

> A stored routine is a set of SQL
>   statements that can be stored in the
>   server.

The idea is to store SQL queries on your SQL server.

You should proceed to other way round. Access your SQL Server from MATLAB, eventually calling stored procedures. All you need is a jdbc driver, leveraging MATLAB's Java scripting capabilities.